# Ember.Array: how can I make several changes atomically?

Tags: arrays, ember.js, atomic

I have an Ember.Array that I need to rearrange by moving one element to another. Right now, I have the function:

```
moveElement: (from, to) ->
  from_value = array.objectAt(from)
  array.removeAt(from)
  array.insertAt(to, from_value)
```

The problem is, I use this array in a computed property and that is firing in between the `removeAt` and `insertAt`. How can I make sure these changes are atomic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to get it working by using `arrayContentWillChange`, `arrayContentDidChange`, and array primitives:

```
moveElement: (from, to) ->
  array = @get('array')
  # make all changes to array atomically
  array.arrayContentWillChange(from, 1, 0)
  from_value = array[from]
  array.splice(from,1)
  array.splice(to,0,from_value)
  array.arrayContentDidChange(to, 0, 1)
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the `arrayContent..Change` functions correctly. They take 3 arguments: `startIdx`, `removeAmt`, `addAmt`. Which represent the start index, number of elements to remove, and number of elements to add. I used my `from` and `to` values to show that I am removing one element at `from` and adding one element at `to`.

Seems to be working now.